# Prob: Expected Area from Moment Generating Fuction

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Question: Find the moment generating function of the normal distribution function N(μ,σ).  A machine cuts rods to a nominal length of a meters.  It is found that the lengths are normally distributed with mean μ=a and standard deviation σ=b meters. (Note that the standard deviation is in the same units as the mean, unlike the variance.)  The ends of pairs of rods are welded together to form a right angle.  What is the expected area of the triangle formed by the rods?

So, I'm just starting introductory stochastic analysis and I'm a little confused by this problem.

The moment generating function for a normal distribution is $M_x(t)$=$e^{(tμ+\frac{1}{2}σ^2t^2)}$, but I don't understand as to how I'm supposed to find expected area from this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are the lengths of the two rods, the area is $XY/2$.   Presumably $X$ and $Y$ are to be assumed independent (the question doesn't say this, but it should).

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ functions, or just variables?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are [random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable).

Comment: Thanks, I just find it odd that the question should be so simple.

Comment: Don't worry, you'll get enough complicated questions later on.